# "Generalized Unitary Matrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A unitary matrix is an $N\times N$ (square) complex-valued matrix $\mathbf{A}$ satisfying:

$\mathbf{AA^\dagger} = \mathbf{I}_N$

where $\mathbf{I}_N$ is the identity matrix and $^\dagger$ stands for conjugate transpose operator.

Suppose an $N\times N$ (square) complex-valued matrix $\mathbf{B}$ satisfies:

$\mathbf{BB^\dagger} = \mathbf{D}_N$

where $\mathbf{D}_N$ is some diagonal matrix.

What can be said about $\mathbf{B}$ ?

I am particularly interested in the condition number or similar properties reflecting a degree of orthogonality or isometry property.

Comment: Is $\mathbf{AA^\dagger}$ $A$ multiplied by its pseudo-inverse, or is it $A$ multiplied by its conjugate transpose?

Comment: conjugate transpose. Sorry for failing to mention that.

Comment: For what it's worth, if $B$ is invertible then there exists a positive definite diagonal matrix $C$ such that $CB$ is unitary (namely $C=\sqrt{D_N^{-1}}$).

Comment: On top of Jonas' comment, if you are using conjugate transpose, then $D_N$ has to be nonnegative because the diagonal entries of $BB^\dagger$ is taking the norm-squared of the rows of $B$.  If there are $0$ entries in $D_N$, then the full row has to be zero. And of course, the rows are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: On top of Evan's comment : your property just states that the column vectors of B are orthogonal, with (squared) norms given on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
AA^\dagger=D_N
$$
iff all rows of $A$ are pairwise orthogonal.  It is not necessarily the case that the columns of $A$ are pairwise orthogonal.  As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Which satisfies the about property, but does not have orthogonal columns.

Similarly
$$
A^\dagger A=D_N
$$
iff $A$ has orthogonal columns, but under these circumstances, $A$ may not have orthogonal rows.

---

It is interesting to note that any matrix for which
$$
AA^\dagger = D_N
$$
Can be decomposed into the form
$$
A = DU
$$
for some diagonal matrix $D$ and some unitary matrix $U$. Similarly, any matrix for which
$$
A^\dagger A = D_N
$$
Can be decomposed into the form
$$
A = UD
$$
for some diagonal matrix $D$ and some unitary matrix $U$.

You should be able to answer any further questions using this fact.